# Jsoup stop rendering code inside <pre> tag

Tags: jsoup

Here is sample my code

```
    String unsafe = 
      "<p onClick=''><a href='http://example.com/' onclick='stealCookies()'>Link</a></p><pre><iframe></iframe></pre><img src=''/>";
    String safe = Jsoup.clean(unsafe, Whitelist.basic());        
    System.out.println(safe);
```

here i want to keep code inside `pre` tag as it is so that user can type his code.
But jsoup is escaping `iframe` inside `pre` tag. How can i keep code inside `pre` as it is ?

Will it be safe to keep code inside `pre` as it is ?

Answer (score 1):

No, that is completely unsafe. Don't do it.

The `<pre>` tag is not treated specially by the HTML parser or renderer. It just has the following CSS applied to it by the user agent stylesheet:

```
pre {
    font-family: monospace;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

HTML tags present within the `<pre>` behave completely normally — for instance:

```html
<pre>
    Here is preformatted text
    with <b>bold</b>
    and <a href="about:blank">links</a>
    and an iframe:
    <iframe src="about:blank" width="150" height="100"></iframe>
</pre>
```

If you want to display user content in a `<pre>` tag, you need to HTML escape it, just like you would anything else.